# Invoke a method without using the class name and scope resolution operator

Tags: c++, class, namespaces

When invoking a standard method, for example, `std::sort()`, we just need a namespace and can further simply by `using namespace std;`
How can I do this with a user-defined class or is it impossible. (No pre-processor macro solution please). I tried using this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
namespace std
{
    class A
    {
    public:
        static void foo()
        {
            std::cout << "foo";
        }
    };
}
int main ()
{
    //foo(); does not work
    A::foo(); //Only this works
}
```

Replacing `std` by any other namespaces also doesn't work.

Comment: you are not allowed to add an `A` to the `std` namespace. Irrespective of how you call the method, the code has UB

Comment: why is `foo` not a free function? If you want it to be a free function, just make it one

Comment: Putting everything ugly together, it can be done: [demo on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/046f109b791a9c91). But I carefully would remove any traces which could lead back to me being the author... ;-)

Comment: Can you give an example what is not working?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I tried using other namespaces but none of them work

Comment: Just in case you didn't know, `cin` or `std::cin` is not a method, it's an object (an `std::istream`).

Comment: what are you actually trying to achieve? Frankly, this looks like lazyness of typing which is common among beginners. Scopes are a good thing and there are good reasons to write `A::foo` instead of `foo` when `foo` is from `A`. From a design point of view `foo` should not be a (static) member of `A` in the first place, because it doesn't need to be

Comment: Change your `namespace` to `test`. Then remove your current `using namespace std;` and in `main` write `using namespace test`. So `int main( ) { using namespace test; A::foo( ); }`

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Yes, I know, but I was just wondering if it works or not

Answer (score 2):

> When invoking a standard method, for example, std::sort(), we just need a namespace and can further simply by using namespace std; How can I do this with a user-defined class [...]

`std::sort` is a template not a function, but otherwise it is not different from code you can write yourself:

```
 namespace foo {
       void bar() {}
 }

 using namespace foo;

 int main() {
     bar();   // ok
 }
```

This works for namespaces but not for members of classes (there is `using` for members of classes to bring something from a base class scope into the derived class scope, but thats a different topic and beyond the scope of the question (no pun intended), it is not what you are asking for here).

In your example there is no reason why `foo` should be a member of `A`, hence you should make it a free function (as above). Supposed you didn't write `A` but you still need to call it without qualifiying the class name you can wrap it in a free function.

Also note that you are not allowed to add something to namespace `std`. If you do, your code has undefined behavior.

And finally, note that there are good reasons to discourge usage of `using some_namespace;` altogether. Consider this:

```
   namespace foo1 {
         void bar(){}
   }
   namespace foo2 {
         void bar(){}
   }

   // lots of other code

   using namespace foo1;

   // lots of other code

   int main() {
         foo1::bar();    // this is bar from foo1
         foo2::bar();    // this is bar from foo2
         bar();          // to know which bar this is you have to 
                         // look for any using directive, ie 
                         // it makes your code much harder to read
   }
```

Code is written once but read many times. The 6 extra characters to type pay off in more clear code. See also:
[Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)